# Git Extensions doesn't show up in VS 2010 Professional

Tags: git, git-extensions

I have just installed git extensions, but it doesn't seem to show up under my tools menu. I have tried to install it two times, but with no luck.

Anyone got an idea why it doesn't show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git extensions are adding main menu item `Git` and new toolbar. There're nothing related to them in `Tools`.

Comment: Oh, I just looked at the tutorial video, which might be a little outdated. I guess I need to have my glasses checked :)

Comment: @Dofs: GitExs have convenient commit dialog (reset chunk and diffs inplace) and VS integration. TortoiseGit has great history viewer (GitExs are missing several usable features). Everything else is the best from console window from my experience. I hope it would be helpful for you if you're just starting with GUI on Win :)